# How to use stream listener i.e db.collection.watch() in mongodb and flutter

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, amazon-ec2

Hi I want to listen to data changes in mongodb using the db.collection.watch() function. Could any one let me know how to use it. I am using mongodart package run in AWS EC2 server.

[image]

The attached image is a collection name 'cart' . I want to listen to it whenever a change is made that is a document is added or deleted it would change the count .
Earlier i used firestore where i can use stream builder to do so. But i am new to app development so learning daily . It would be helpful if any one could let me know how to use it